# How to upload file in jhipster form?

Tags: file-upload, angular5, jhipster

I am just starting to use jhipster 5 and angular 5. I have a form and in that form in addition to few regular fields, I have a file input.

I could not find any documentation on how to file in jhipster.

**EDIT 1:**

I could somehow managed to upload file and send to server. Below is my server method to handle the form submission.

```
@PostMapping("/email-jobs")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<EmailJobDTO> createEmailJob(MultipartFile file, @Valid @RequestBody EmailJobDTO emailJobDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save EmailJob : {}", emailJobDTO);
        if (emailJobDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new emailJob cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }

        System.out.println(file.getName() + " File Name ");

        EmailJobDTO result = emailJobService.save(emailJobDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/email-jobs/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Here i get following exception,

```
Unsupported Media Type: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary73sdwuJtdeRk6xsO;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

If I remove @RequestBody from method signature then I dont get above exception but then I start getting 400 bad request exception saying my form fields can not be null.

Comment: Have you defined a blob field in your entity?

Comment: I tried adding blob field but it was not working. Whenever I click on browse and upload file. It gives error.

Comment: I have updated my question with few more details.

Comment: Why did you change JHipster generated code by adding File parameter. The blob is expected in your DTO.You can't say you did not find doc in JHipster for this when you changed code manually.

Comment: blob will get stored in the database. I just want to upload a temp excel file, read that excel file and then store data in excel in the db. I don't want to store the file in the database.

Comment: OK but the principle is the same at REST controller level.

Answer (score 0):

You must define MultipartFile is `@RequestParam` and declare `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in post mapping, like:

```
@PostMapping("/email-jobs", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Client side, you can try send request as this:

```
Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/path',
            data: {
                file: yourdatafile
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }).progress(function (evt) {
            // handle progress
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // handle success
        });
```

Comment: Where does Upload come from?

Comment: You can try ng-file-upload

Answer (score -1):

Instead of uploading a file, create a field type as a BLOB and then in your business logic, make a file if u need or else do your.